# tcl tk teacup install from file

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Hi I am trying to install the latest version of treectrl ( http://tktreectrl.sourceforge.net/ ) however if i run `teacup install file://C:/tktreeunzipFolder` it errors can't overwrite file.

THe file is a file in the temp folder which is generated by the script. What is the correct way to install a package from a directory/tar.gz with teacup?

(I would like to use the local version, since I want to use column headers in the new way of 2.4.1, since I expect the other method to become depreciated soon)

I would also like to know how to use a package with a precompiled part without installing it. I.e. are there any special steps I need to mkae the package accessible once I have the package file in a subdirectory of the skript I run. (I am not allowed to install packages on one machine but would like to use them anyhow in one script). Do I have to register the files (dll/so) somehow? (note I can't sudo on linux).

Adding the dll/package to a subdir of the workingdirectory yields the following error (under windows):

> couldn't load library
>   "Z:/files/tcl/encounterXtract/treectrl_win/treectrl24.dll": invalid
>   argument
>       while executing "load Z:/files/tcl/encounterXtract/treectrl_win/treectrl24.dll treectrl"
>       ("package ifneeded treectrl 2.4.1" script)
>       invoked from within "package require treectrl"

**sidenote:**

> under linux/unix it is fine to just put the files in a subdirectory
>   and add it to auto_path with `lappend auto_path path_to_sub_dir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you *have* to run the command as a user that has permission to write to the local repository of installed packages. For Windows, that *might* require you to run the `teacup install` as administrator (NB, I'm not sure that the installation package for tktreectrl is called `tktreectrl.dll`; I suspect it's called something else but don't know what):

```
runas /user:administrator "teacup install C:\path\to\tktreectrl.dll"
```

However, the fact that the main teacup archive isn't carrying the treectrl 2.4.1 package is a problem all of its own. Have you tried dropping a line to the people at [ActiveState](http://community.activestate.com/forums/activetcl-discussion)?

Comment: i am running teacup from a tcl-shell as a user with almost full admin privileges (installing software, including tcl, from scratch works). I wonder what happens to the supplied pkgIndex.tcl file and the treectrl.tcl file that accompany the dll if I follow your instructions. Being able to put the dll in a subdir and load it from there would suffice for me. However if I try to do so I get the error added to the question.

Comment: i asked active state, thanks for the deep link, if you are interested: http://community.activestate.com/node/8689. ANd I think you know why teacup update does not work for me, the file is not in the repository for me